# http/1.0 and deflate/gzip

Tags: http, deflate

Is http/1.0 able to handle deflated and gzip content?
I've finished to implement deflate and gzip in my minimalist web server and I don't really know if browsers with http/1.0 are capable to handle deflate and gzip compressed content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well really it's down to the browser; not the protocol (HTTP 1.0 does allow for compression quite happily)

You should be examining the [Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Accept-Encoding) header, which will either be gzip, deflate. If the header isn't there then don't compress.

Comment: One problem with gzip compression and HTTP 1.0 is that in many circumstances you won't be able to have keep-alive connections with it. This is due to not being able to use chunked transfer encoding so it applies when gzip is done on the fly. It'll just downgrade to a regular non keep alive connection in this case though. Also if the files are pre-gzipped and the server can output the Content-Length header at the start this is not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be different interpretations of what `deflate` means. HTTP 1.1 specifies [RFC 1950](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html) (zlib) format but IIS produces a raw [Deflate](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951.html) stream instead. Internet Explorer cannot handle an RFC 1950 stream - it interprets the `deflate` Content-Encoding as RFC 1951 - so you may want to avoid that format entirely.

The .NET `DeflateStream` *only* implements the Deflate compression algorithm, it does not create the Zlib format.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this rather extensive list](http://www.computec.ch/projekte/browserrecon/scan/accept-encoding.fdb). (short answer appears to be : Yes they do).