# Http get ungzip response in bash

Tags: bash, unix, gzip, deflate, zcat

I need to manually ungzip response of the following page: http://muaban.net/ho-chi-minh.html

I'm doing

```
echo -e "GET /ho-chi-minh.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: muaban.net\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n" | nc muaban.net 80 > response.txt
```

until response actually contains `Content-Encoding: gzip` or `Content-Encoding: deflate` header (sometimes it's just plain text), then

```
cat response.txt | sed '1,14d' | zcat
```

but it says input is not in gzip format.

Here are the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=67
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: deflate
Expires: Wed, 16 May 2012 15:20:31 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 May 2012 15:18:31 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Proxy: 162
Date: Wed, 16 May 2012 15:19:23 GMT
Content-Length: 12618
```

Comment: What does the returned data look like? does it have a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header?

Comment: Added headers to the post. After them it's just a gzipped block of data.

Comment: Works for me? [tmp]$ echo -e "GET /ho-chi-minh.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: muaban.net\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n" | nc muaban.net 80 > response.txt
[tmp]$ cat response.txt | sed '1,14d' | zcat > response.html

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
[tmp]$ head -n 2 response.html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: [tmp]$ zcat --version
zcat (gzip) 1.4
Copyright (C) 2007, 2009-2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Eggert.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240104/900873) that indicates IIS uses the wrong deflation format. But it seems the site in question randomly returns either `deflate` or (the correct) `gzip`, which is why David Souther was able to `zcat` it (I got gzip once out of several tries). So you'll probably want to loop and fetch it until you get a gzipped version (probably should include a delay and/or max tries).

Comment: Have you tried seeing if it works when you take those lines out manually? And see what `file` says about it without the lines. IIRC, the first two bytes should be 'GZ', is that what you see?

Comment: but how browsers are handling raw deflate? is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: @spacevillain : if you system has it, try using `uncompress` on your data when it is marked deflate. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9170338/9186091) about the confusion over the meaning of "deflate" as an HTTP content encoding.

It is best to simply [not accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) deflate and only accept gzip.  Then the server won't deliver deflate.

If you accept deflate, then you must be prepared to try decoding it both as a zlib stream (which is what the HTTP standard specifies) or as a raw deflate stream (which is what Microsoft servers apparently would deliver in error).  Then use the one that decoded properly.

Neither the zlib nor raw deflate formats are gzip, and so zcat would not work on either.

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the encoding to "identity", that site returns plain text to you.