# Gzip compression not working stil

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

I have enabled mod_rewrite, mod_deflate, mod_headers and mod_setenvif in Apache and not mod_gzip, mod_filter.

**Tried**

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>


# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

I have also tried enabling Gzip Compression in wp admin by changing it to 1 even though it uses php in header to compress by Gzip.

Still gzip is not working. Any one help me with this.

Made the test in https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: Check here http://checkgzipcompression.com/  gzip has enabled or not on your server.

Comment: GZIP is Enabled  Compressed size 4,933 bytes

Comment: on which page you are getting its not enabled on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ ?

Comment: I have tested it in 5 to 8 pages it shows the same, Home page also.

Comment: Can any one help me with this checkgzipcompression.com(Enabled), developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights(No Gzip), I have enabled mod_deflate on my server and added the Gzip compression code to htaccess, Still its not working, Trying hard to get this issue solved but cant fix

Comment: tested with curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://yoursite.com/somefile
  0    20    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 10:13:55 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I have Content-Encoding: gzip  and I have HTTP/1.0 do I need to use 1.1

Comment: I have Accept-Encoding header, with gzip, deflate so it should work in HTTP/1.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239512/http-1-0-and-deflate-gzip